# How can I query on a composite primary key with Fluent NHibernate and QueryOver?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover, composite-key

I have a list of `Funds`, each of which has an `ID`, `ConfigID` and a `CountryID`. I need to select `FundPerformances` for each `Fund`, based on these IDs.

The `FundPerformance` table has a composite primary key of `ID`, `ConfigID` & `CountryID`.

So far, I have

```
perfs = _session.QueryOver<FundPerformance>()
            .Where(xx => xx.ConfigId == _configId)
            .Where(Restrictions.In(Projections.Property<FundPerformance>(t => t.Id), funds.Select(xx => xx.Id).ToArray()))
            .Where(Restrictions.In(Projections.Property<FundPerformance>(t => t.CountryId), funds.Select(xx => xx.CountryId).ToArray()))
            .List<FundPerformance>().ToList();
```

I don't think this is going to work because it's selecting on the individual fields, and not the composite ID.

What do I need to do to select the data properly?

This is the current FundPerformance mapping class:

```
public class FundPerformanceMap : ClassMap<FundPerformance>
{
    public FundPerformanceMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("FundPerformanceStatistics_FundId");
        Map(x => x.CountryId).Column("FundPerformanceStatistics_FundCountryId");
        Map(x => x.ConfigId).Column("FundPerformanceStatistics_ConfigId");

        Map(x => x.OneMonth).Column("FundPerformanceStatistics_OneMonthBack");
        Map(x => x.ThreeMonth).Column("FundPerformanceStatistics_ThreeMonthBack");
        Map(x => x.YTD).Column("FundPerformanceStatistics_YearToDate");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something else

```
public class Fund
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

    public virtual Config Config { get; set; }

    public virtual IDictionary<Config, FundPerformance> Performances { get; private set; }
    public virtual FundPerformance ActualPerformance { get { return Performances[Config]; } }

}

public class FundPerformance
{
    public virtual Fund Fund { get; set; }
    public virtual Config Config { get; set; }

    public virtual int OneMonth { get; set; }
    public virtual int ThreeMonth { get; set; }
    public virtual int YTD { get; set; }
}

public class Config
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class FundMap : ClassMap<Fund>
{
    public FundMap()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Id, "FundId")
            .KeyProperty(x => x.CountryId, "FundCountryId");

        HasMany(x => x.Performances)
            .KeyColumns.Add("FundPerformanceStatistics_FundId", "FundPerformanceStatistics_FundCountryId")
            .AsMap(fp => fp.Config)
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Component(c =>
            {
                c.ParentReference(x => x.Fund);
                c.References(x => x.Config, "FundPerformanceStatistics_ConfigId");
                c.Map(x => x.OneMonth, "FundPerformanceStatistics_OneMonthBack");
                c.Map(x => x.ThreeMonth, "FundPerformanceStatistics_ThreeMonthBack");
                c.Map(x => x.YTD, "FundPerformanceStatistics_YearToDate");
            })
    }
}

// Query
var someCountry = session.Load<Country>(5); <- get the Country with id 5 without going to the db (proxy when not already loaded) only to have the reference

var key = new Fund { Id = 1, Country = someCountry }
var fund = session.Get<Fund>(key);
var performanceByConfig = fund.Performances[_config];
```

Original answer:

if Fund has a compositeKey then FundPerformance should have one, too. Also i think a Reference to Fund is more OOP-like:

```
public class FundPerformance
{
    public virtual Fund Fund { get; set; }

    public virtual int OneMonth { get; set; }
    public virtual int ThreeMonth { get; set; }
    public virtual int YTD { get; set; }
}
```

Either map it as Component (because it looks like something dependant)

```
public class FundMap : ClassMap<Fund>
{
    public FundMap()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Id, "FundId")
            .KeyProperty(x => x.CountryId, "FundCountryId")
            .KeyProperty(x => x.ConfigId, "ConfigId");

        HasMany(x => x.Performances)
            .KeyColumns.Add("FundPerformanceStatistics_FundId", "FundPerformanceStatistics_FundCountryId", "FundPerformanceStatistics_ConfigId")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Component(c =>
            {
                c.ParentReference(x => x.Fund);
                c.Map(x => x.OneMonth, "FundPerformanceStatistics_OneMonthBack");
                c.Map(x => x.ThreeMonth, "FundPerformanceStatistics_ThreeMonthBack");
                c.Map(x => x.YTD, "FundPerformanceStatistics_YearToDate");
            })
    }
}
```

or as an Entity with composite key

```
public class FundPerformanceMap : ClassMap<FundPerformance>
{
    public FundPerformanceMap()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(x => x.Fund, param => param
                .Column("FundPerformanceStatistics_FundId")
                .Column("FundPerformanceStatistics_FundCountryId")
                .Column("FundPerformanceStatistics_ConfigId"));

        Map(x => x.OneMonth).Column("FundPerformanceStatistics_OneMonthBack");
        Map(x => x.ThreeMonth).Column("FundPerformanceStatistics_ThreeMonthBack");
        Map(x => x.YTD).Column("FundPerformanceStatistics_YearToDate");
    }
}

// Query
var key = new Fund { Id = 1, CountryId = 2, ConfigId = 3}
var fund = session.Get<Fund>(key);
var performances = fund.Performances;
```

Comment: Hi @Firo, thanks for this. Sorry I'm only getting back on this now, but I was tied up with other stuff for most of today. I'm a little confused by something though. You've stated that `Fund` should have a `CompositeId` mapping to include `ConfigId`. I'm not sure this will work because the Fund table doesn't have a ConfigId column. It's only in FundPerformance. Would that work? Or could I just specify specify a Fund CompositeId mapping of ID & CountryID?

Comment: your first sentence "I have a list of Funds, each of which has an ID, ConfigID and a CountryID." let me think you have. What is the purpose of configId in the Fundperformance then?

Comment: Sorry - I didn't meant to make it confusing. The ConfigID in FundPerformance relates to how the performance was calculated. A Fund has a Property Config ID which is used to determine which performance it is supposed to select.

Comment: Thanks for the time you spent on this. It turns out that I found a different solution to the issue, so I can't mark yours as correct. I've voted it up though, because it was helpful and you went out of your way to try to help. Thanks.

Comment: then post your solution and accept it so others can have it too

Comment: This doesn't really seem to address the core issue, which is how to query for *multiple* records matching a specific known subset of composite key values. Just doing a `Session.Get` is going to be terribly inefficient if you need to look up several of these.

Comment: then you can easily query for them with eager fetching the association